# Installation of Skype failed. How to install Skype from Ubuntu's package manager?

Tags: apt, skype

After clicking 'Install' button, I have this screen. How to install Skype on Ubuntu from **Ubuntu's package manager**? I've installed Skype manually by downloading it, but can't update it after that - Skype suddenly says `Update only with package manager`.

[image]

Upd 1:

[image]

Comment: Go to the Ubuntu Dash and search for "Software & Updates". Open it up and then go to the "Other Software" tab. Do you see anything with skype (eg `https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main`) listed? If so, what is the address listed?

Comment: If you've installed it manually - what way to install it did you use ? Deb ? Snap ?

Comment: @JayDin, Yes, I have that line there. But what do you mean `address listed`? Where may I see it? I have added a screenshot to question

Comment: @RobertRiedl, I don't remember for sure now, but apparently it was `deb` because I don't know what `snap` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first photo, it seems that you try to install skype as a snap package from the gnome software. You said that you installed skype manually by downloading it, but you didn't say if you got the *snap* version or the *deb* version.

From the second photo, I assume that since the repo of skype is there, you installed the *deb* version.
Given that, the problem is that the repo of skype, as illustrated in second photo, is disabled.
You have to enable it in order to get updates.

For clarification, check my repolist including skype repo:
[Skype repo enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ardpg.png).

NOTE: the skype package in the repo is named `skypeforlinux` : [Skype package in the repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeOQQ.png)

Comment: The first part of your answer didn't work out. I enabled Skype repo in "Software & Updates" but Ubuntu kept throwing error. The second part solved the issue. I installed Skype by `$ sudo apt-get install skypeforlinux`